# Correlation/Factor loadings do not change sign after reverse coding?

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis

I am helping a client analyze a dataset using Factor Analysis, and I am completely stuck on an issue I can't resolve. The scale contains 14 items, 8 making up one subscale and 6 making up another subscale. The items are worded so that for the 8 items, a higher score (1-5 Likert) indicates more of the quality being measured, and for the 6 items, a higher score (1-5 Likert) indicates less of the quality being measured. Theoretically, the two qualities (both negative qualities) being measures should be positively correlated (more of negative quality A indicates more of negative quality B). If I run EFA, I correctly identify two factors by any criteria (Kaiser, Parallel Analysis, Scree-plot, etc.). For the 6 items that are worded in the opposite direction, all factor loadings are negative, which is - I believe - expected, given the fact that a lower score indicates LESS of the quality measured.

However, if I reverse-score all items belonging to the 6-item subscale, and rerun the factor analysis, the correlations between the items switch directions (now, all items in the 14 item scale are positively correlated) and if I sum the scales, and visualize them on a scatterplot, there is a clear positive relationship (as opposed to the non-reversed case, where the relationship between the summed scales is negative). However, if I rerun Factor Analysis, the factor loadings for the 6-item scale are still negative, and the estimated factor scores are negatively correlated, regardless of estimation method.

Otherwise, KMO is high, communalities are acceptable, but the determinant is indicated in SPSS as being 0.000. In every other case I've seen where the determinant has been zero, SPSS was not able to estimate factor scores, or even converge, so I'm assuming this is just a result of SPSS rounding off the determinant at the 3rd decimal.

The only other thing that's worth mentioning is that the original article where the scale was developed used Varimax rotation. If I use varimax, the loadings have the appropriate sign, and the resulting factor scores are also (very weakly) positively correlated. However, I don't think the use of an orthogonal rotation is appropriate here, as the two constructs measured are theoretically assumed to be correlated.

What may be the cause of factor score correlations not switching sign even after reverse coding? Unfortunately, I'm unable to include a minimal reproducible example as the data is sensitive, and it is not my own.

EDIT: Some more information: Running the same analyses in R, R reports the determinant as 0.00004, which is above 0.00001. Nonetheless, the factanal() function does not converge ("system is computationally singular"). The fa() function, however, does, both using Maximum Likelihood and Minres methods. Model fit is also appropriate. Interestingly, Maximum Likelihood also converges in SPSS, and produces expected results (factor correlation is positive when items are reverse coded, negative when not) as opposued to Principal Axis Factoring, which consistently produces the wrong sign (negative) for the correlation in both softwares, regardless of how items are scored.